# Cleverbot api not working (python 2 to python 3)

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert an module that interact with Cleverbot. It's on python 2, but I would like it to be working with python 3. But I encounter an error :

`parsed = [ item.split('\r') for item in self.resp.split('\r\r\r\r\r\r')[:-1]]
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

I don't know how to resolve it ! Please help !

Here is the entire code :

```
"""Python library allowing interaction with the Cleverbot API."""
import hashlib
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from urllib.request import *


class Cleverbot:



 """
    Wrapper over the Cleverbot API.

"""
HOST = "www.cleverbot.com"
PROTOCOL = "http://"
RESOURCE = "/webservicemin"
API_URL = PROTOCOL + HOST + RESOURCE

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,'
              'application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-us,en;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Host': HOST,
    'Referer': PROTOCOL + HOST + '/',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache'
}

def __init__(self):
    """ The data that will get passed to Cleverbot's web API """
    self.data = {
        'stimulus': '',
        'start': 'y',  # Never modified
        'sessionid': '',
        'vText8': '',
        'vText7': '',
        'vText6': '',
        'vText5': '',
        'vText4': '',
        'vText3': '',
        'vText2': '',
        'icognoid': 'wsf',  # Never modified
        'icognocheck': '',
        'fno': 0,  # Never modified
        'prevref': '',
        'emotionaloutput': '',  # Never modified
        'emotionalhistory': '',  # Never modified
        'asbotname': '',  # Never modified
        'ttsvoice': '',  # Never modified
        'typing': '',  # Never modified
        'lineref': '',
        'sub': 'Say',  # Never modified
        'islearning': 1,  # Never modified
        'cleanslate': False,  # Never modified
    }

    # the log of our conversation with Cleverbot
    self.conversation = []
    self.resp = str()

def ask(self, question):
    """Asks Cleverbot a question.

    Maintains message history.

    Args:
        q (str): The question to ask

    Returns:
        Cleverbot's answer
    """
    # Set the current question
    self.data['stimulus'] = question

    # Connect to Cleverbot's API and remember the response
    try:
        self.resp = self._send()
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
        # request failed. returning empty string
        return str()

    # Add the current question to the conversation log
    self.conversation.append(question)

    parsed = self._parse()

    # Set data as appropriate
    if self.data['sessionid'] != '':
        self.data['sessionid'] = parsed['conversation_id']

    # Add Cleverbot's reply to the conversation log
    self.conversation.append(parsed['answer'])

    return parsed['answer']

def _send(self):
    """POST the user's question and all required information to the 
    Cleverbot API

    Cleverbot tries to prevent unauthorized access to its API by
    obfuscating how it generates the 'icognocheck' token, so we have
    to URLencode the data twice: once to generate the token, and
    twice to add the token to the data we're sending to Cleverbot.
    """
    # Set data as appropriate
    if self.conversation:
        linecount = 1
        for line in reversed(self.conversation):
            linecount += 1
            self.data['vText' + str(linecount)] = line
            if linecount == 8:
                break

    # Generate the token
    enc_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(self.data)
    digest_txt = enc_data[9:35]
    token = hashlib.md5(digest_txt.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    self.data['icognocheck'] = token

    # Add the token to the data
    enc_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(self.data)
    binary_data = enc_data.encode('utf-8') 
    req = urllib.request.Request(self.API_URL, binary_data, self.headers)

    # POST the data to Cleverbot's API
    conn = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    resp = conn.read()

    # Return Cleverbot's response
    return resp

def _parse(self):

    """Parses Cleverbot's response"""
    parsed = [ item.split('\r') for item in self.resp.split('\r\r\r\r\r\r')[:-1]]

    return {
        'answer': parsed[0][0],
        'conversation_id': parsed[0][1],
        'conversation_log_id': parsed[0][2],
        'unknown': parsed[1][-1]
    }

quest=input("Question: ")

cb = Cleverbot()
quest=cb.ask(quest)
print(quest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `self.resp` is a bytestring, and you probably want to decode it before you work on it.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually made it work using raw strings.